# How add CheckBox in CustomControl based on TreeView Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview, itemtemplate

I have custom control based on `TreeView` and need add to my `CheckedTreeViewItem` based on `TreeViewItem` `CheckBox` binded to `CheckedTreeViewItem.IsEnabled` property.
I tried add `CheckBox` to `TreeView.ItemTemplate`, but if write this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="ItemCheckBox" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

`CheckBox` appears only on first `CheckedTreeViewItem`.

if i write like this:

But only CheckBoxes visible.

Update: Sorry for not adding code, i don't now that this is so important. I write TreeView with CheckedObjects logic, because i can't wrap my object in ViewModel in my project. I've already written ListBox with that logic and it's very very useful for me.

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Class="TestControlsLibrary.CheckedTreeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:testControlsLibrary="clr-namespace:TestControlsLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <!-- Need specify that for each CheckedTreeViewItem need draw CheckBox, with possibility to use DisplayMemberPath for content in item-->
</TreeView>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class CheckedTreeView : TreeView
  {
    public CheckedTreeView()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedItemsProperty;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedChangedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ItemCheckedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ItemUnCheckedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedItemsChangedEvent;

    static CheckedTreeView()
    {
      CheckedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedItems", typeof (IEnumerable), typeof (CheckedTreeView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ArrayList(), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCheckedItemsChanged)));
      CheckedChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckedChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof (RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool>), typeof (CheckedTreeViewItem));
      ItemCheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ItemChecked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof (RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>), typeof (CheckedTreeView));
      ItemUnCheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ItemUnChecked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof (RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>), typeof (CheckedTreeView));
      CheckedItemsChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckedItemsChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof (RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<IEnumerable>), typeof (CheckedTreeView));
      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof (CheckedTreeView), CheckedTreeViewItem.CheckedEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(checkedEventHandler));
      EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof (CheckedTreeView), CheckedTreeViewItem.UnCheckedEvent,
        new RoutedEventHandler(unCheckedEventHandler));
    }

    private static void checkedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedTreeView = (CheckedTreeView) sender;
      var item = (CheckedTreeViewItem) e.OriginalSource;
      var collection = checkedTreeView.CheckedItems;
      collection.Add(checkedTreeView.Items);
      checkedTreeView.CheckedItems = new ArrayList(collection);
    }

    private static void unCheckedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedTreeView = (CheckedTreeView) sender;
      var item = (CheckedTreeViewItem) e.OriginalSource;
      var collection = checkedTreeView.CheckedItems;
      collection.Remove(item.Items);
      checkedTreeView.CheckedItems = new ArrayList(collection);
    }


    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<IEnumerable> CheckedItemsChanged
    {
      add { AddHandler(CheckedItemsChangedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(CheckedItemsChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> ItemChecked
    {
      add { AddHandler(ItemCheckedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(ItemCheckedEvent, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> ItemUnChecked
    {
      add { AddHandler(ItemUnCheckedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(ItemUnCheckedEvent, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable CheckedItems
    {
      get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(CheckedItemsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CheckedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnCheckedItemsChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var checkedTreeView = (CheckedTreeView) sender;
      var args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<IEnumerable>((IEnumerable) e.OldValue, (IEnumerable) e.NewValue);
      args.RoutedEvent = CheckedTreeView.CheckedItemsChangedEvent;
      checkedTreeView.RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
      return (item is CheckedTreeViewItem);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
      return new CheckedTreeViewItem();
    }
  }

  public class CheckedTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
  {
    public static DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckChangedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent CheckedEvent;
    public static readonly RoutedEvent UnCheckedEvent;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
      get { return (bool?) GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool> CheckChanged
    {
      add { AddHandler(CheckChangedEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(CheckChangedEvent, value); }
    }


    static CheckedTreeViewItem()
    {
      IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof (bool?), typeof (CheckedTreeViewItem),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCheckChanged)));
      CheckChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CheckChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof (RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<bool>), typeof (CheckedTreeViewItem));
      CheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Checked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof (RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof (CheckedTreeViewItem));
      UnCheckedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("UnChecked", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof (RoutedEventHandler),
        typeof (CheckedTreeViewItem));
    }

    private static void OnCheckChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var CheckedTreeViewItem = (CheckedTreeViewItem) sender;
      var oldValue = (bool?) e.OldValue;
      var newValue = (bool?) e.NewValue;
      if ((bool) e.NewValue && !(bool) e.OldValue)
      {
        var argch = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedTreeViewItem.CheckedEvent);
        CheckedTreeViewItem.RaiseEvent(argch);
      }
      else if (!(bool) e.NewValue && (bool) e.OldValue)
      {
        var argun = new RoutedEventArgs(CheckedTreeViewItem.UnCheckedEvent);
        CheckedTreeViewItem.RaiseEvent(argun);
      }
      var args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<bool?>(oldValue, newValue);
      args.RoutedEvent = CheckedTreeViewItem.CheckChangedEvent;
      CheckedTreeViewItem.RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<CheckedTreeViewItem> GetListItems(CheckedTreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
      foreach (var item in treeViewItem.Items)
      {
        yield return (CheckedTreeViewItem)treeViewItem.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
      }
    } 


    private void SetIsChecked(bool? value, bool updateChildren, bool updateParent)
    {
      if (value == IsChecked)
        return;

      IsChecked = value;

      if (updateChildren && IsChecked.HasValue)
        GetListItems(this).ToList().ForEach(c => c.SetIsChecked(IsChecked, true, false));

      if (updateParent && this.Parent != null)
        (this.Parent as CheckedTreeViewItem).VerifyCheckState();

     // this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }

    private void VerifyCheckState()
    {
      bool? state = null;
      foreach (var item in GetListItems(this))
      {
        bool? current = item.IsChecked;
        //if (i == 0)
        //{
        //  state = current;
        //}
        //else if (state != current)
        //{
        //  state = null;
        //  break;
        //}
      }
      this.SetIsChecked(state, false, true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to overwrite `Template` of TreeViewItem. Why are you doing that?

Comment: You need to write HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate with CheckBox.

Comment: @RohitVats Because this code worked nice with `ListBox`, i still able to use `DisplayMemberPath` and get required view with `CheckBox` and Content on each ListBoxItem. But may be I'm on the wrong way.

Comment: It isn't clear how your original question relates to this new code.  Have you written a `ControlTemplate` for `CheckedTreeViewItem`? If you want to add a checkbox to the mess, that would certainly be the place to look.

Comment: @mcwyrm I'm trying to do so `CheckedTreeView` would look like `TreeView` but with `CheckBox` on each Item. I don't know  how exactly do this. In `ListBox` i used style and ControlTemplate for `CheckedListBoxItem`.

Comment: `TreeView.ItemTemplate` is a `DataTemplate`. You can - quite easily, too - add a checkbox to each item via `TreeView.ItemTemplate` and I posted an answer showing how to do so. If you want to extend `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem` then you will need to write `ControlTemplate`s for both of them. (Btw, if you are just trying to display the `IsSelected` status of each item there are far, far easier ways to go about it.)

Comment: @mcwyrm Can you show some code for `ControlTemplate`? In the second code in my post I was trying to write a `ControlTemplate`, but it did not work.

Comment: You could start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I urge you to write your extension as a custom control, not a user control. I clearly don't understand all your requirements, but it is possible you could achieve what you're after by setting the `ControlTemplate` in `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` rather than by extending `TreeViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find `TreeView`s easier to work with, as a rule, if you put *default* `DataTemplates` in `TreeView.Resources` (or some other appropriate resource dictionary).

The specific trick you're trying to get with the check box can be pulled of by using `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}"`.

I would recommend something like this (I took the liberty of making up couple of dummy datatypes):

```
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Folder}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Selected"
                              IsEnabled="False"
                              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:File}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />

                    <CheckBox Content="Selected"
                              IsEnabled="False"
                              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you were trying to add a `CheckBox` to `TreeView.ItemTemplate`.